# Using System.Net.WebClient with HTTPS certificate

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest, certificate, http-post

In my C# Windows client, I have a POST submission to "the mothership". I want the data in the submits to be secured, of course, so I paid for HostGator to issue me an SSL certificate.

I saved off the .CER file, and I'm constructing the request as such:

```
//wrapper for WebClient object to use certificate file
class SecureWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        string certPath = @"e:\mycertificate.cer";
        X509Certificate myCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath);
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(myCert);
        return request;
    }
}

//request
private static SecureWebClient client = new SecureWebClient();
private static NameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add(POST_ACTION, ACTION_CODE_LOGIN);
nvc.Add(POST_EMAIL, email);
nvc.Add(POST_PASSWORD, password);

sResponse = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(client.UploadValues(BASE_URL + ACTION_PAGE, nvc));
```

Its throwing a System.Net.WebException:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

The InnerException is a System.IO.IOException:

> The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.

Any insight on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want the SSL cert on the client or the server?

Comment: To clarify: do you want the communication encrypted (you need the certificate on the server)? Or do you want to authenticate the client (you need a client certificate)? To be specific, you'll need a private key (a .PFX file, probably) on the relevant end.

Comment: I am not entirely well versed in the ways of security. I can access the host site in a browser with HTTPS protocol. I want to post data to the exact same server/site with encryption. So, @SLaks - I'm not sure, technically speaking, what I want. I just know in layman's what I need as described above.

Comment: @Roger - please see above (I can only add 1 @ tag per comment)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're **not** using *client* certificates and you **can** access your server using **https://** then your code should look like:

```
private static WebClient client = new WebClient();
private static NameValueCollection nvc= new NameValueCollection();

nvc.Add(POST_ACTION, ACTION_CODE_LOGIN);
nvc.Add(POST_EMAIL, email);
nvc.Add(POST_PASSWORD, password);

sResponse = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(client.UploadValues(BASE_URL + ACTION_PAGE, nvc));
```

As long as your **BASE_URL** uses **https://** then all the data (to and from the server) will be encrypted.

IOW using SSL/TLS from a client to a server does not require the client to do anything special (with the certificate), besides using **https://** as the scheme, since the operating system provides everything (e.g. trusted roots) you need to secure the data transmission.

Comment: I did just as you said---my code is just like the code you posted, and my BASE_URL is `https://www.myserver.com/`, but I am getting the exact same error messages as described in the original post. _NOW_ what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Split your issue into pieces. First are you able to use WebClient to download your main page (using https://www.myserver.com/) ? If that does not work then ensure it works from a web browser (and check the page properties to ensure it was encrypted). If that works then try your upload code without SSL, i.e. on http://www.myserver.com/ to ensure this part works. It's likely that one part won't be working and that will give you (and us) some hint to help you.

Comment: using `client.DownloadData("https://www.myserver.com/")` _works_. then using `client.UploadValues("http://www.myserver.com/")` _also works_. What does this mean?

Comment: That's weird, the next logical culprits would be the server-side code (not that I see how it could result in that particular exception) or some server misconfiguration. If I had such an issue I would (a) install wireshark and look at SSL packets (but that's not an easy option) then (b) try using another tool/language to do the same (i.e. make sure its on the server side). Maybe you should ask on http://serverfault.com/ ?

Comment: So I tried `client.UploadValues("https://www.myserver.com/", nvc)` and it _worked_ (to my surprise). Then I boldly decided to go for gold and try the ORIGINAL REQUEST: `client.UploadValues(BASE_URL + ACTION_PAGE, nvc)` and it **worked**. Why?

Comment: Not sure, I guess you posted no data and that the inner exception text is not very helpful (sadly a common occurence) ?!? I'm glad your issue is solved.

Answer (score 4):

**Client** certificates will work **only** if the private key is available. This is not *generally* the case when using .cer files since the X.509 certificate does **not** include the private key.

The only *safe* way to ensure the private key is available is to load the certificate from a PKCS#12 file where both the certificate(s) and the private key are available (i.e. both were exported into the **.pfx** file).

Notes:

- I said **generally** because Windows/CryptoAPI sometimes does some *magic* (when used with X509Certificate) and automatically associate a certificate with a private key from the certificate.key stores.
- I said **safe** because that will work on Mono too, not just MS .NET.

Comment: This is way over my head. Where do I get/make/find a PKCS#12 file? And how do I load the private key from it?

Comment: First make sure you *want* client certificates :-) Your source code is (mis)using this feature but it's not clear it's what you want. If you only want "https" from the server then you don't need to handle certificate from your client application.

Comment: I want to secure the data my WebClient.UploadValues call. Thats all I really know how to convey. So I ask you: do I _need_client certificates?

Comment: no, see my other answer (which is not based on client certificates)

Comment: @poupou: You Sir, are awesome! I was trapped with this .cer problem for quite some time, now with a .p12 exported key all is working smoothly without the need to import the keys into the keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are doing it backwards.  You should have the SLL Certificate installed on the web host/server.  Then you create a web request to web server and requires the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: I am not entirely well versed in the ways of security. I can access the host site in a browser with HTTPS protocol. I want to post data to the exact same server/site with encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect to your server with RDP

Open IE and go to Internet Options

Navigate to Advanced Tab and Enable both Use SSL 2.0 and SSL 3.0

Now your server requests will be authenticated