# how do i load a certificate into visual studio?

Tags: .net, security, networking, https, webclient

I want to use Visual Studio to post data to a server via HTTPS. I know that when I go to that URL in my browser, the server sends back a certificate verifying its identity (as a part of the HTTP on top of SSL protocol). I am having trouble posting to the server via VS (I get a web exception) and I think it is because I am missing the certificate. The sys admin has emailed me a certificate that I think I need to load. When I go to Properties-->signing-->select from file -->and pick the certificate then VS throws an error `"The selected file does not contain a private key. You must choose a certificate that contains a private key."` This error message is confusing to me because I would think that the certificate from the server DOES NOT have the private key, only a verified public key. The unexpected error message makes me think that I am loading the cert incorrectly. Am I loading correctly? If so, then why is VS saying that it expects a private key?

Here is the code that posts via VS

```
 Using client As New Net.WebClient
            Dim uploadThis As String = some string
              client.UploadString(uploadThis,   "POST", uploadThis)
  End Using
```

Comment: How are you attempting to do the POST from Visual Studio? Via code, or via some tool or...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson via code. I added the code to my question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using System.Net.WebClient with HTTPS certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402752/using-system-net-webclient-with-https-certificate)

Comment: It has nothing to do with Visual Studio or SSH, so remove both tags. If the server certificate is self signed or faked, you should install its root certificate to your test machine so the client side can trust the server side test certificate. When you saw the error message on private key, you simply used a wrong certificate file. Microsoft article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648498.aspx documents carefully on how to generate and install test certificates on both sides.

Answer (score -2):

I tried looking the error message on google.
                                                                                            http://www.1-script.com/forums/security-microsoft/issuing-code-signing-certificate-with-private-key-22023-.htm

These people seem to think that you need to make a v2 certificate.
So sorry but I have no idea what any of that means, I just was bored. 
Have a good day.

Comment: This is not an answer even if I understand why you got bored